# Matrix operations in business

Tags: predictive-models, references, optimization, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a chemical engineering background but I have decided to go into the corporate world instead of industry. I now work in payment streams and have been doing data science and optimizations. What I found use of was a distance matrix of entities and then doing clustering. I am now looking for similar matrix operations in which I could use in payment streams or corporate business. Linear algebra in engineering was taught for one purpose and I’m now trying to apply similar concepts in business. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could be even, more specific about intended applications.  I would look into books about mathematical tools for social science, should be a big overlap.  One forthcoming book (don't know when it will be published) is:  Greenacre, M. and Nenadić, O. (2015): “Mathematical Tools for Social Scientists: An Introduction to R”  but you could write the first author,  which (offtopic!) even has a nice youtube channel for statistical songs:  https://www.youtube.com/user/StatisticalSongs

Other ideas would be to look for econometrics or time series books, there are recommendations on this site:
[Econometrics textbooks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/econometrics-textbooks)

Some books which are used to teach mathematics to economics students could be useful:

Sydsæter, K., Hammond, P. and Strom, A. (2012): “Essential Mathematics for Economic Analysis”, 4th ed., Pearson.

Sydsæter, K., Hammond, P., Seierstad, A. and Strom, A. (2008): “Further Mathematics for Economic Analysis”, 2nd ed., Pearson.